# How to access the JSON created by swagger at compile time using Dropwizard Testing?

Tags: swagger, dropwizard

I have a simple Dropwizard application with swagger integrated and I want to access the JSON created by swagger at compile time using Dropwizard Testing. Is this possible, and If it is, please guide me how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use swagger-core for the generation of your Swagger spec. Swagger-core is a *runtime* library and produces the documentation as part of your running application.

There is a community contribution of a [maven plugin](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin) that you can use to generate static documentation during the build process. Keep in mind that it may differ from the output of swagger-core as it basically scans the annotations but does not necessarily employ the same business logic of the generation process.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware that **maven plugin** is available for generating static documentation but my real question is that, is it possible to access the http://localhost:8080/api-docs/resouce link using Dropwizard testing to check whether the resource is correct or not. And if yes then how to do it?

Comment: The answer stands. You asked whether it can be done in compile time, and the answer is that the only way to do it is using the maven plugin. swagger-core itself only produces the docs at runtime and is not available at compile time.